# A few questions about topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Statement $1$: Given a non-constant map $f: (\mathbb R, \tau_{cocountable}) \to (\mathbb R, \tau_{cofinite})$, show $f$ is continuous iff, for each $y \in \mathbb R$, the set $f ^{–1}(\{y\})$ is countable

> Proof of Statement $1$: Suppose $f$ is continuous. For each $y \in \mathbb R, \ \{y\}$ is $\tau_{cofinite}$-closed, so $f^{–1}(\{y\})$ must be $\tau_{cocountable}$-closed ($\ne \mathbb R$ since $f$ is non-constant), **therefore** $f^{–1}(\{y\})$ is countable. Suppose now $f^{–1}(\{y\})$ is countable for each $y \in \mathbb R$. For any closed $K \in (\mathbb R, \tau_{cofinite}), \ K$ is either $\mathbb R$ or *finite*. Now $f^{–1}(\mathbb R) = \mathbb R$ is $\tau_{cocountable}$-closed, and if $K$ is finite, then $f^{–1}(K) = \bigcup_{y \in K}f ^{–1}(\{y\})$ is a finite union of countable sets, therefore countable, therefore $\tau_{cocountable}$-closed again and hence $f$ is continuous.

**My Questions about the proof above**:

How does the bolded "**therefore**" above follow? By definition, any(?) subset $X$ in the domain of $f$ is of the form $\mathbb R = X \cup X^c$ where $X^c$ is the countable complement of $X$. But that makes $\mathbb R$ countable.

In the other direction, how does the italicized *finite* follow? If $K$ is finite, then $\mathbb R = K \cup K^c$ implies $\mathbb R$ is finite.

In general, does $\tau_{cocountable}$ contain countable sets and does $\tau_{cofinite}$ contain finite sets? And maybe trivially, how do we know $f^{-1}(\mathbb R) = \mathbb R?$

---

> Question $2$:

> Are the following pairs of spaces homeomorphic?

> (i) $\mathbb Q \cup (0, 1)$ and $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ (as subspaces of $(\mathbb R, \tau_{usual}))$;

> (ii) $(\mathbb C, \tau_{disc})$ and $(\mathbb C, \tau_{cocountable})$;

> (iii) a circle with one point removed (in $\mathbb R^2$ with $\tau_{usual}$) and $(\mathbb R, \tau_{usual})$;

> (iv) $\mathbb N$ with topology $\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{5, 6\}, \{7, 8\}, \ldots$ and all unions of these, and $\mathbb N$ with topology $\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{5, 7\}, \{6, 8\}, \{9, 11\}, \{10, 12\}, \ldots$ and all unions of these.

The following have answers

> (v) $(\mathbb R, \tau_{cocountable}), \ (\mathbb R, \tau_{cofinite})$

> (vi) $\mathbb R^2$ and the surface of a sphere with one point removed (natural metric
> topologies here)

> (vii) $(\mathbb Q,l_x), (\mathbb Q, l_y)$, where $x, y$ are two distinct rational numbers and $l_p$ is included-point topology

Book's answers to (v) and (vii):

> (v) No. The statement ‘there is a countably infinite closed subset’ is
> (obviously) a homeomorphic invariant, is true in $(\mathbb R, \tau_{cocountable})$ and is false in $(\mathbb R, \tau_{cofinite})$

> (vii) Yes. The map $h : \mathbb Q → \mathbb Q$ given by $h(x) = y, h(y) = x, h(z) = z$
> when $z \ne x$ or $y$ is routinely checkable to be a homeomorphism.

**My answers/questions regarding question $2$ above**:

(i) $\mathbb Q, (0, 1)$  are not compact and so their union is not compact meaning there's no continuous inverse function from $\mathbb Q \cup (0, 1)$

(ii) Any function from a discrete space to an indiscrete space is continuous. Since idenity $i$ is continuous and bijective, $i$ should work here to show homeomorphism

(iii) I think this is a special case of [Stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection)

(iv) Any inverse image of an open set in $\mathbb N$ is a union of $2$-sets. Since the given $2$-sets are open, their union is open as well. This works in both directions, so a continuous function with its continuous inverse likely exists. I am not sure how to find a concrete homeomorphism, but would $f(x, y) = (x, y – 1)$ if $y$ is odd and $f(x, y) = (x + 1, y)$ if $x$ is even work?

Are my answers to (i) through (iv) correct? If not (or if incomplete), how do I improve them?

(v) This question might be trivial, but I am still new to the very basics of topology. Consider $f: (\mathbb R, \tau_{cofinite}) \to (\mathbb R, \tau_{cocountable})$. Every $Y \in (\mathbb R, \tau_{cocountable})$ must have a pre-image $X \in (\mathbb R, \tau_{cofinite})$. By definition, every $X$ is open, but for $f$ to be continuous $X$ must be cocountable. Correct?

(vi) It's yet another special case of Stereographic projection. Correct?

(vii) Is $h(y)$ a typo? Did they mean $h^{-1}(y)?$

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't carefully read your question, but I'd highly recommend deleting everything below the horizontal line, and posting it as a new question. Shorter, more focussed questions will gather more answers, while longer questions with a large number of parts may be closed for being too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll only get into 1, for focus:

In the co-countable topology the only **closed** sets are $\Bbb R$ and all countable sets (including all finite subsets and also $\emptyset$). As $f$ is not constant, $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is ruled out (or $f$ would have been constant with value $y$).

$f$ is continuous iff the inverse image of every closed set is closed. So the condition is necessary as indeed all sets $\{y\}$ are closed in the cofinite topology.

It's sufficient as all **closed** sets of the cofinite topology are $\Bbb R$ and all finite subsets. $f^{-1}[\Bbb R]=\Bbb R$ (this just says that any $x \in \Bbb R$ is mapped into $\Bbb R$ under $f$, which is a given)  and this is closed in any topology on $\Bbb R$. A finite set is a finite union of singletons and the condition on $f$ tells us that all singletons have closed inverse images and as $$f^{-1}[\{y_1,\ldots, y_n\}]=\bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1}[\{y_i\}]$$  and trivially also $f^{-1}[\emptyset]=\emptyset$ we see that all inverse images of closed sets are closed and thus $f$ is continuous.

The cofinite topology on $\Bbb R$ does not contain any finite set except $\emptyset$, as $\Bbb R$ is infinite.

The cocountable topology on $\Bbb R$ does not contain any countable set except $\emptyset$, as $\Bbb R$ is uncountable.

(recall that a closed set is defined as the complement of an open set).

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. All the elements $X$ in the co-countable topology $\tau_{cc}$ are open by definition of topology. No countable set $X^c$ belongs in $\tau_{cc}$ by definition of $\tau_{cc}.$ Then since closed set is defined as the complement of an open set, $X^c$  must be closed. As reals are both open and closed, the only closed element in $\tau_{cc}$ must be $\mathbb R.$ Since $f^{-1}(\{y\}) \ne \mathbb R$ and  $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed,  $f^{-1}(\{y\}) \not \in \tau_{cc}$ meaning it's countable.

Comment: @user947160 No, not quite. If an element is *not* in $\tau_{cc}$ it can be countable or uncountable. We only know it's not $\emptyset, \Bbb R$ and its *complement* is *not* countable. E.g. a set like $(0,1) \subseteq \Bbb R$ is not in the topology, as its complement is uncountable. A set $C$ is countable iff $\Bbb R\setminus C$ has countable complement (trivially) iff $\Bbb R\setminus C$ is open so in $\tau_{cc}$ iff $C$ is closed. The only other closed set is the complement of $\emptyset$, i.e. $\Bbb R$ itself.

Comment: @user947160 WE often *define* the topology $\tau_{cc}$ as $C$ is closed iff $C=\Bbb R$ or $C$ is at most countable.